# Producing Pythagorean triples with identical legs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Can someone check if this is correct?

Apply **Proposition 1** to find two new pairs of Pythagorean triples with identical legs.

> **Proposition 1:** (original image [proposition 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anWlv.png))
>   $$
> (a,b,c)=
> \begin{cases} 
>       (4(2k+1),4k(k+1)-3,4k(k+1)+5)\\
>       (4(2k+1),16k(k+1)+3,16k(k+1)+5) 
> \end{cases}
> $$

$4(2k+1)$, assume $k = 2  $

$2nm=20$, so        $a=20$

$4k(k+1)–3$ =      so $b=21$

$4k(k+1)+5$        so $c=29$

$n^2-m^2=21$

$n^2+m^2=29$

Solving the equations $n=5, m=2$ where $n>m>0$ 
$\gcd(n,m)=1$

Comment: No two triples have identical legs.  It is easy to find many triples matching a single side but, with 2 matching sides,  they would have to be the same triangle.

Comment: Is my answer correct? so are you saying this proposition is wrong?

Comment: I'm not saying you cant find two triples with your  formula but none will have $2$ identical legs.

Comment: I've replaced the image with latex (you can find basic here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). It is preferable to have math typeset this way (one of many reasons is that images are not friendly for search engines). However the question seems to have errors (for example there is $4k(k+1)-3=$ without right side, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Your proposition does find those two triples and perhaps it works for all values of $k$ but sometimes, there are more than $2$ triples with a given side length.

To find triples with matching sides A or B, see my answer to another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006351/can-two-pythagoras-triplet-have-a-common-number/3589506#3589506). You may notice that there are more than $2$ triples with the same even side in the examples below taken from my answer link.

$$f(6,5)=(11,60,61)\qquad f(10,3)=(91,60,109)\qquad f(15,2)=(221,60,229)\qquad f(30,1)=(899,60,901)\qquad $$

$$f(7,6)=(13,84,85)\qquad f(14,3)=(187,84,205)\qquad f(21,2)=(437,84,445)\qquad f(42,1)=(1763,84,1765)\qquad $$

The subset of triples where $GCD(A,B,C)=(2x-1)^2, x\in\mathbb{N}$ includes all primitives where $GCD(A,B,C)=1$ and here is a sample where $n$ is a set number and $k$ is a count or "depth" within a set. How does your formula fit in?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5   &  k=6  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 & 13,84,85 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 & 45,108,117 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 & 85,132,157 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 & 133,156,205 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 & 189,180,261 \\ \hline
Set_{6} &143,24,145 &165,52,173 &187,84,205 &209,120,241 &231,160,281 & 253,204,325 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
In every set, all triples have $C-B=(2n-1)^2$ and the increment between values of $A$ is always $2(2n-1)$ where $n$ is also the set number. My formula for generating them is:
$$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\quad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\quad C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2$$

I gather you are trying to generate all primitives with a single variable formula. Is that true?

Comment: I didn't see that there is a rule to choose k , maybe worth to check again , I checked it's valid for any integer positive number

Comment: I should have said in my answer that it may not find all triples. See my update.